# Are there infinitely many pairs of primes $(p,q)$ such that $p^2+1=2q$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For example, $(3,5), (5,13)$ or $(11,61)$ satisfies this condition, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove that such pairs exist infinitely many. Is there any prior researches about it?

Comment: Interesting that someone (anonymously) voted to close this query.  Given the responses (i.e. answers) that this query has received, what was the OP supposed to do - show work on what is actually an unsolved problem?

Comment: OP should be able to prove the Riemann Hypothesis if he wants to be in MSE @user2661923

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OEIS/A048161](https://oeis.org/A048161) says

> A048161: Primes $p$ such that $q = (p^2 + 1)/2$ is also a prime.
>
> Primes which are a leg of an integral right triangle whose hypotenuse is also prime.
>
> It is conjectured that there are an infinite number of such triangles.

So, no one knows whether infinitely many such pairs exist.

Comment: I didn't know that the same conjecture already exists, even though I felt I have searched enough! Thank you for finding such a clear and simple evidence.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered by the [generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture#Generalized_Bunyakovsky_conjecture) (aka generalized Dickson conjecture), for the polynomials $f_1(x) = 2x+1$ and $f_2(x) = 2 x^2 + 2 x + 1$.
However, the only case where this conjecture is known to be true is for just one polynomial of degree $1$ (Dirichlet's theorem).

Comment: I'm surprised that someone had same questions more than a hundred years ago. Thank you for giving me an advice.